# Boolean checkbox status update in ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, toggle, selectbooleancheckbox

I have two Boolean type check box in my jsf page from which second check box is made disabled depending upon the first check box status and for first time page loading both the check box are unchecked. I am updating the second check box disable status through script when first check box is checked.Then i am selecting second check box.
       But the problem is when i am submitting my page only first check box status is getting updated. This is my Managed Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "checkBoxTest")
@SessionScoped
public class CheckBoxTest {
    private boolean check1;
    private boolean check2;
    public boolean isCheck1() {
        return check1;
    }
    public void setCheck1(boolean check1) {
        this.check1 = check1;
    }
    public boolean isCheck2() {
        return check2;
    }
    public void setCheck2(boolean check2) {
        this.check2 = check2;
    }
    public String update(){
        boolean status = this.isCheck1();
        boolean status2 = this.isCheck2();
        return "checkboxExample.xhtml";
    }
}
```

This is my jsf page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
   <h:head>
      <title>JSF tutorial</title>
      <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myFunction.js">
      </script>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <h2>CheckBox Example</h2>
      <h:form id="form">
        <h:outputLabel value="First Check"/>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox name="check1" id="check1" value="# {checkBoxTest.check1}" onclick="changeCheckBox2Status()">  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputLabel value="Second Check"/>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox name="check2" id="check2" value="#{checkBoxTest.check2}" disabled="#{checkBoxTest.check1?false:true}">   </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:commandButton action="#{checkBoxTest.update()}" value="Submit2">
        </h:commandButton>
      </h:form>      
   </h:body>
</html>
```

My script is given below

```
function changeCheckBox2Status(){
        var checkBox1Status = document.getElementById("form:check1");
        if(checkBox1Status.checked){
            document.getElementById("form:check2").disabled=false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The serverside is not aware of the javascript update that you've made and as a result, it won't be reflected on server-side components. Use jsf/ajax to update your components instead

Comment: i'm just changing the disable status but not the value through script which i think is not the issue that should be reflected in server side. And for ajax update as suggested by you, thanks for your suggestion... But in my real situation i have to update many check boxes depending up on the status of first check box which i think is a performance issue if i make server side call.

Comment: please update if any one have any solution to this problem. I am stuck here only and can not proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
public void setCheck1(boolean check1) {
    this.check1 = check1;
    this.check2 = !this.check2;
}
```

and similarly for the other.

Comment: but this will always make the second check box status checked even if this is actually kept unchecked in page.

Comment: Your logic is bad. When you check one of them, you should uncheck the other, to make the two events mutually exclusive.